# Digression in the set of attributes in Richfaces 4.0?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I'm implementing file uploading using Richfaces version 4.0. I've noticed, that there is quite a big differences between `rich:fileUpload` component in [version 3.2](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_fileUpload.html) and the one in the [latest version](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs.html#sect-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs-richfileUpload). As I see, there aren't possibility to set automatic uploading or limit number of downloaded files. I can't set auto clear option as well. Am I right? Could you point the reason of this or suggest a solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is that RichFaces guys have spent enormously a lot of time in migrating the component library from JSF 1.x to JSF 2.x. So some things have to be prioritized. In order to be "in time" with a JSF 2.0 compatible component library (to prevent users from changing the component library to another JSF 2.0 compatible one such as PrimeFaces; PrimeFaces for JSF 2.0 was already out half 2009 while RichFaces for JSF 2.0 was out by end of 2010 only, more than one year later!), they have scratched some hard-to-implement and/or least-used features for RichFaces 4.0 and postponed them for RichFaces 4.1 or later. The Flash-based `<rich:fileUpload>` was one of them. It does now not use Flash anymore, but plain HTML/CSS/JS and hence the capabilities are very minimal.

Currently there are several [`rich:fileUpload` feature and enhancement requests](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20RF%20AND%20%28summary%20~%20fileupload%20OR%20description%20~%20fileupload%20OR%20comment%20~%20fileupload%29%20AND%20issuetype%20in%20%28Enhancement,%20%22Feature%20Request%22%29) open for RF 4.1. There are plans to let it utilize HTML5 and XHR2 powers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The *maxFilesQuantity* attribute was added as part of RichFaces 4.1.0.M3 (see [RF-10996](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-10996)).

At the time of this answer, RichFaces [4.1.0.M4](http://blog.bleathem.ca/2011/11/richfaces-410m4-release-announcement.html) is already available, so I'd recommend you use that instead.

If you are stuck on RichFaces 4.0.0.Final until 4.1.0.Final is released, you could use a *fileUploadListener* to count the number of files uploaded, and limit it that way.

Comment: Thanks for advice,but how can I hide 'add' button in the components interface?

Comment: @nikagra The 'add' button automatically hides when you've added maxFilesQuantity files.  It's hidden by setting the display style attribute to none.  You can do that with some of your own custom javascript, should you have different conditions for hiding the add button.